# Printing source-code line numbers in Xcode 7.2

Tags: xcode, printing

I can't seem to find a way to print Swift 2.0 Xcode 7.2 source code line numbers to my printer.

Is this possible? Is it a setting? If so, can someone post graphic snapshots of the menus/settings where I can enable this? If not, detailed instructions on how to add or use a script? I'm a total newbie learning programming.

Thanks in advance.